# Erro Rails Assets. Javascript não funcionando corretamente (Datepicker)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

Estou querendo adicionar o [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)  ao meu projeto. Fiz da seguinte maneira.

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'font-awesome-sass',                  '~> 4.5.0'
  gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap-sass',        '~> 3.3.6'
  gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap-datepicker',  '~> 1.6.0'
end
```

**_form.html.erb**:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2">
      <%= f.input :publish_at, as: :string, input_html: { class: 'datepicker', 
            value: (Time.now + 1.day).strftime('%d/%m/%Y') } %>
   </div>
</div>
```

Criei um arquivo chamado **datepicker.js** dentro de app/assets/javascripts:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  language: 'pt-BR',
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  startDate: '0d',
  autoclose: true,
  keyboardNavigation: false,
  todayHighlight: true
});
alert("hello");
```

O **alert** está funcionando, entretanto é como se não estivesse pegando a classe '.datepicker' do meu **_form.html.erb**. Quando eu coloco o mesmo código javascript dentro do meu **_form.html.erb** dentro de um script tag o datepicker funcina perfeitamente, porém eu não queria inserir a tag  script em cada view que contenha um datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo usar a gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'.

Em app/assets/stylesheets/application.css, adicione:

`*= require bootstrap-datepicker3`

E em app/assets/javascripts/application.js

`//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require_tree .`

E na sua view

`<input type="text" data-provide='datepicker' >`

Caso queira chamar a função via javascript coloque ela dentro de:

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  });`

Adicione também a gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~> 2.1' caso você use turbolinks

E pronto, deve funcionar. [link para documentação](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/bootstrap-datepicker-rails/1.6.0)

Comment: Eduardo, apenas através do atributo data-provide eu não poderei editar algumas coisas do datepicker como o formato, a linguagem... como coloquei no meu arquivo datepicker.js. As soluções via rails-assets (rails-assets.org) são melhores que as gems. Não era o que eu estava procurando, mas obrigado.